# Returned date value is not same as stored in database

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, jpa, java.util.date

In java code, I have TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));  and use java.util.date to interface with date value from database.

Mysql database is located in eu-west, and field is defined as "datetime" (also tried timestamp)

I am using JpaRepository to interact with database.

When I persist date value such  as "Tue Dec 24 22:19:37 UTC 2019", and it is saved correctly. 
However, when i retrieve the value it is shown as "Wed Dec 25 06:19:37 UTC 2019" which is 8 hours of ahead original value.  I also checked that it is under time zone "UTC"

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Might be the time is automatically translated to your local time zone when you read it.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `TimeZone` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead depending on the capabilities of your JPA implementation use for example an `Instant` or an `OffsetDateTime` with offset 0 (UTC). Both are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Don’t.

Never set the JVM’s current default time zone, except as a last desperate solution to certain problems. Doing do affects all code in all threads in all apps running in that JVM. And doing so is not a solution to your problem.

> and use java.util.date to interface with date value from database.

Don’t.

That class is terribly flawed, and is now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

As of JDBC 4.2 and later, represent a moment using `OffsetDateTime`.

> Mysql database is located in eu-west,

“eu-west” is not a time zone. Use only [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in format of `Continent/Region` such as `Europe/Paris`.

> and field is defined as "datetime" (also tried timestamp)

Are you tracking moments, specific points on the timeline? The do NOT use `DATETIME` as the column data type. That type lacks the concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Use only `TIMESTAMP`.

I avoid JPA, do I cannot help you there. I can show plain JDBC code.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

If you follow this kind of code using smart objects instead of dumb strings, you’ll have no problems with time zone.

If you go other routes, you may find various tools in the middle between the database and your app may implicitly apply some time zone to the moment retrieved from
the database. While well-intentioned, such features are unfortunately very confusing and conter-productive.

Comment: Thanks for help. new time api fix problem for me when I set database field to be either datetime/timestamp. The reason i still use datetime is because I might have time before 1970.

Comment: @xibrian Just be aware that you are hacking the data types. Be sure to adjust all your date-time inputs to UTC before storing as `DATETIME` in MySQL. And you might consider using a more advanced database with better date-time handling, such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL).